# Build a sequence of numbers

Tags: excel

My goal is to build a automatic coordinates file from a X and Y pitch for X and Y steps.
Let say,
X pitch = 2 (mm) Y pitch = 1 (mm)
X steps = 10 and Y steps = 10

My file should like something like this

```
    1, 0, 0
    2, 2, 0
    3, 4, 0
    4, 6, 0
    5, 8, 0        
    6, 10, 0
    7, 12, 0
    8, 14, 0
    9, 16, 0
    10, 18, 0
    11, 0, 1
    etc 
    (till 100)
```

With the sequence function I managed too build to first column of numbers
=SEQUENCE(L1*L2;1;1;1) L1=Xsteps L2=Ysteps

Now I am struggeling to build the X and Y column
While X is repeating after every step for 10 times, Y is only incrementing every 10 times.

I would like to automate it, because in real life it's never a nice round number. But how?

Comment: I was a bit confused by this, but are you saying that X goes up in steps of 2, but in row 11 instead of going up to 20,  it resets to zero and Y increases by 1?

Comment: Plz see my comment - I think OP should have put dots ... between 4 and 11 to show that X & Y continue to increase in the same way until row 11 where x resets and y increments. First column must just be a row number, the other 2 columns are x & y.

Comment: edited my question a bit.
I started counting at 0, that is way step 20 has the number 18

Comment: I don't understand what the rules are for the four columns (X pitch,Y pitch,. X step, Y step) and why are there only 3 columns in the example?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is maybe not complete, but I started with row:

```
1     0             0
=A1+1 =MOD(B1+2,20) =IF(MOD(A2,10)=0,C1+$D$1,C1)
```

This creates following list:

```
1   0   0   10308
2   2   0
3   4   0
4   6   0
5   8   0
6   10  0
7   12  0
8   14  0
9   16  0
10  18  10308
11  0   10308
```

Comment: it's a start but not what I'm looking for.
Column 2 should adding up until row 10, {2;4;6;8;10;12;14;16;18)

Comment: ... but it's a start, so what's missing?

Comment: edited my question. You repeated 0 to 8, while it should repeat 0 to 18...and what if the number is 10308 instead of 2, how to I increment that?

Comment: I edited my answer for going up to 18. As for the modification of the step, you can simply change the formula correspondingly.

Comment: thanks, I will try that
something else
in this formula: =IF(MOD(A2,10)=0,C1+1,C1) ,I can't change C1+1 to C1+'any cell number' is that working at your end?

Comment: You can simply put `C1+10308` instead of `C1+1`, no problem. In case you have put the number in a fix cell, like `$D$1`, you can put `C1+$D$1`, the dollar-sign will make sure the value doesn't change.

Comment: @Niles: I adapted my answer again.

Comment: Thanks, that easy! Ok, got the third column working...but not the second one.
I am not really sure how the MOD function is working. Can you help me out with my real numbers? I got 17 steps, and an increment of 10380. After 17 steps the same numbers keep repeating

Comment: The [mod function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mod-function-9b6cd169-b6ee-406a-a97b-edf2a9dc24f3) causes the repetition, just like you asked (after 18, start back at 0).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241002/discussion-between-niles-and-dominique).

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365, you can use Let with Sequence:

```
=LET(rows,Xsteps*Ysteps,
seq,SEQUENCE(rows,1,0),
column1,seq+1,
column2,MOD(seq,Xsteps)*Xpitch,
column3,INT(seq/Xsteps)*Ypitch,
CHOOSE({1,2,3},column1,column2,column3))
```

[image]

The four cells A2, B2, C2 and D2 are assigned names using the Name Manager based on the names in A1, B1, C1 and D1 respectively.

Comment: Wow, looks very nice, but I can't reproduce it :-(
You probably give some cells a specific name, like rows and seq and column1
Can you help me out?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I did assign names to Xpitch, Ypitch, Xsteps and Ysteps using Name Manager - will add to my answer. The other names rows, seq, column1, column2 and column3 are assigned within the Let statement. I could have chosen to do it all in the Let statement.

Comment: it's not only that..those I also found, but thanks for editing.
Two diferent things, my system uses ; as a seperator, but I can change the formula ofcourse,
But I got an error on the function: SEQUENCE(rows;1;0), In the functionbox it says in red #NAME?

Comment: That's interesting, I get the same thing when I go into the function box, but it still works in the worksheet and I can also run through it OK using Evaluate Formula. I wonder if this is a known issue - will try googling it.